# my program prints out a different result from what expected

Tags: c++, operators, operations

so every time i try to put an "n" in, the first line will put out a number that is equal to n+1. so please help me what i did wrong! thank you

```
#define _SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS
#include "../../../std_lib_facilities.h"
int main()
{
cout << "Enter a number: ";
double n;
cin >> n;
cout << "n: " << n
    << "\n++n: " << ++n
    << "\nThree times of n: " << n * 3
    << "\nTwice n: " << n + n
    << "\nHalf of n: " << n / 2
    << "\nSquare root of n " << sqrt(n);
int m = n;
cout << "\nInteger of n: " << m
    << "\nRemainder when divide n by 2: " << m % 2
    << "\nDivision when divide n by 2: \n" << m / 2;
keep_window_open();
}
```

Comment: ++n increases n by one. type (n+1) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n++` changes the value of `n`. None of your other expressions do. That fact that you get `n+1` makes it pretty clear that the `n++` is being evaluated before all the other "stuff" is output (and so `n` is already incremented).

Answer (score 0):

You are using `n` and doing `n++` (which actually increments `n`) within the same expression. This is [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order).